# toggle/select for changing div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, image

I'm trying to work through building a simple set of div's with corresponding toggle switches(images) shown here;

[question] http://jsfiddle.net/hAJe2/9

HTML:

```
<div id="maindiv">
    <div class="div1">div #1
    </div>
    <div class="div2">div #2
    </div>
    <div class="div3">div #3
    </div>
    <div class="div4">div #4
    </div>
</div>
<div id="imagediv">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/0066cc/ffffff" class="img-swap">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/0066cc/ffffff" class="img-swap">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/0066cc/ffffff" class="img-swap">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/ffff33/000000" class="img-swap">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/ffff33/000000" class="img-swap">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#maindiv{margin:0 auto; text-align:center; font-family:arial, sans-serif;}

.div1{width:100px; height:50px; display:block; background:#33ff33; margin:10px auto;  line-height:50px; display:inline-block;}

.div2{width:100px; height:50px; display:block; background:#33ff33; margin:10px auto; line-height:50px; display:inline-block;}

.div3{width:100px; height:50px; display:block; background:#ff3333; margin:10px auto; line-height:50px; display:inline-block;}

.div4{width:100px; height:50px; display:block; background:#ff3333; margin:10px auto; line-height:50px; display:inline-block;}

#imagediv{background:#cccccc;}

img{margin:10px; cursor:pointer;}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
  $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
      this.src = this.src.replace("0066cc","cccccc");
    } else {
        this.src = this.src.replace("cccccc","0066cc");
    }

    if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
      this.src = this.src.replace("ffff33","ccccc8");
    } else {
        this.src = this.src.replace("ccccc8","ffff33");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass();
  });
});
```

What i want to be able to do is. Div#1, Div#2 are green and Div#3, Div#4 are red by default.

1.if the blue image is clicked, Div's 1, 2 and 3 are green.
2.if the yellow image is clicked, Div's 1 and 4 are green.
3.only one image (out of the five) may be clicked at any given time. So if i click blue, then click yellow, the yellow will override and so Div's 1 and 4 will be green. (Noting that the image that is pressed will change to grey as shown in the example above.)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hAJe2/26/)

i cleaned up your css-code. added data-attributes for handling events. here is the javascript code with comments for what it does

```
$(function(){
  // declare current var for later use
  var current;
  // if an element with the class img-swap is clicked
  $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
     // set this image to grey (dont know if this is the right img url, but seems so)
     $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/80x80');
     // remember if we need to do swap1 (green, green, green, red) or swap 2 (green, red, red, green)
     current = $(this).hasClass('swap1') ? 'swap1' : 'swap2'; 
     // iterate over all our divs
     $('#maindiv div').each(function() {
        // remove the current classes (green AND red)
        $(this).removeClass('red green')
        // get the class from the data-attribute (data-swap1 or data-swap2) and add this class
        $(this).addClass($(this).data(current));   
     }); 
  });
});
```

edit: you probably shouldnt use "green" and "red" for classNames, i just did that for illustration

edit2: if you want a img-swap to only be allowed to be clicked one time, just check for the img-src first in your click-handler: see another update of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hAJe2/27/

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's almost right. What i meant in regards to the img-swap (i should have worded it better) was that there can only be one img clicked at a time. So in essence only one 'grey' img may appear. I also was trying to make the img toggle (off/on, blue/grey, yellow/grey). So if i click blue, div's 1,2 and 3 are green and the img is grey. if i click it again the img returns to blue and the div's return to default (#1,#2 green; #3,#4 red.) The same functionality goes for the yellows.

Comment: It works great. Only is there a way to return the div's to their original(default) set-up;(div#1 green, div#2 green, div#3 red, div#4 red) when their are no grey images. So what i mean is when i click a blue or yellow the div's(green/red) change. when i press that grey image to go back to its original color the div's go back to their default green/red colors. thanks.

Comment: of course it is: http://jsfiddle.net/hAJe2/36/ would be great if you accept my answer if you like ;-)

Comment: Excellent stuff. Thanks for all the help. Quick question if i wanted to get/store the results of the 4 div's (red/green) should/could i wrap it in a form and use the $POST method to a database or store it as an XML, JSON, or TXT file?

Comment: depends on what you want to do with it. if you want to store the selection to "restore" it when the user visits your site, i would use the localStorage. otherwise you have to post/submit it to your server and save it there (database/files ...). if you want to use the LocalStorage think about using cookies as a fallback (<=ie7 does not have the localStorage-support). a complete wrap-up including fallback could be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage (you should definitly use the mdn-docs for javascript help!!!). hint: use JSON.stringify/JSON.parse for saving objects